# How do you define a CSS animation with different timing functions for each property?

Tags: firefox, animation, css, webkit

I am working with keyframe animations in CSS, and I want to be able to specify different timing functions for each property I'm animating.  For instance, during a given keyframe, I'd like to animate opacity from 0 to 1 with an ease-in timing function, and top from 0 to 100 with a linear timing function.

This is possible with CSS transitions, by doing something like the below.  (Unfortunately I need keyframed animations for other reasons.)

```
-webkit-transition-property: opacity, top;
-webkit-timing-function: ease-in, linear;
```

Also, I noticed (at [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-timing-function_tag)) that the specification for the animation-timing-function property accepts a comma delimited list.  However, I don't see any way to specify a corresponding list of properties or any documentation on what the purpose of a list of timing functions is.  Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Answer (score 4):

I find it easier to just use comma separated shorthands:

```
img {
   -webkit-animation:
      updown 2s ease-in infinite,
      rotate 1s ease-out infinite;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/desz9/

Comment: Thanks.  This is actually the workaround that I've been using in the meantime - using two separate animations so that I can specify the timing function on each.  This gets messy when you want to handle the animationend event since now you have to know to wait for N of them before the animation is really over.  Since there is a clean and simple way of doing this with CSS transitions, I was hoping there would be for animations as well.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I don't think there's a way to achieve what you want, but I'd sure be glad to be proven wrong.